# TwitterException+HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am trying to login on twitter through the following code. I have checked the Consumer key and Consumer secret they are correct what I am putting in my code. Still I am facing the exception

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void signIn(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws TwitterException, IOException {

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey("xxx")//xxx=Consumer key
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("yyy");//yyy=Consumer Secret
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());

    StringBuffer callbackURL = request.getRequestURL();
    int index = callbackURL.lastIndexOf("/");

    callbackURL.replace(index, callbackURL.length(), "").append("/callback");

    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("twitter", twitter);

    RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackURL.toString());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);
    response.sendRedirect(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());

}
```

---

Stack Trace:

```
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[10f5ada3-e574403a b8c63e52-c913c2ce b8c63e52-c913c2cc], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}] with root cause
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:34)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:156)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:122)
    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)
    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:281)
    at com.test.web.controller.TwitterController.signIn(TwitterController.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have checked the URL http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=10f5ada3 and http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=e574403a. Still, I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Twitter4j are you using? I had this exact same problem and fixed it by upgrading to the latest version (3.0.5).