# 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

Tags: django, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to add twitter credential to my login system, I keep getting 403 Client Error, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907298/twitterexceptionhttp-response-code-403-for-url-http-api-twitter-com-oauth-r) but doesn't have an answer. I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/issues/164#issuecomment-399730181) no luck.
I tried these patterns with Callback URL no luck:

http://127.0.0.1/

http://127.0.0.1:8000/

http://127.0.0.1/complete/twitter/

http://127.0.0.1/oauth/complete/twitter/

website URL doesn't accept localhost so I put my old website which is not working at the moment. Please help, what's wrong with setting up twitter credential api?

Comment: Localhost / 127.0.0.1 is not supported, you will need to add a domain.

Comment: Great. I added a domain and it worked. thanks